# can't specify target table for UPDATE in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to execute the following query:

```
update table3 d set status = 'Complete'
where d.id in 
(
    select b.id from table1 a, table3 b, table2 c
    where a.id = b.table1_id
    and c.id = b.table2_id
    and c.examId = 16637                 -- will be passed in by user
    and a.id in (46,47,48,49)            -- will be passed in by user
);
```

So, I'm trying to update multiple rows of `table3`.

`table3` is a join table between `table1` and `table2`.

Comment: Your query just works fine. What's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wrap it in a subquery, (*thus creating a temporary table for the result*). I'm also recommending to use `ANSI SQL-92` format.

```
update table3 d 
set    status = 'Complete'
where  d.id in 
(
    SELECT ID
    FROM
    (
        select  b.id 
        from    table1 a 
                INNER JOIN table3 b
                    ON a.id = b.table1_id
                INNER JOIN table2 c
                    ON c.id = b.table2_id
        where   c.examId = 16637 and 
                a.id in (46,47,48,49) 
    ) xx
);
```

or by using `JOIN`

```
update  table3 d 
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT ID
            FROM
            (
                select  b.id 
                from    table1 a 
                        INNER JOIN table3 b
                            ON a.id = b.table1_id
                        INNER JOIN table2 c
                            ON c.id = b.table2_id
                where   c.examId = 16637 and 
                        a.id in (46,47,48,49) 
            ) xx
        ) y ON d.id = y.id
set status = 'Complete'
```

Comment: John, why wouldn't his initial query work? It just looks alright to me

Comment: @nawfal because you can't target the same table that you have joined. I'll give an example. please wait

Comment: @nawfal [see this answer on SO: Update Table with same table in subquery](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12508381/491243). :D